# Webpack: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module browser.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, plugins, webpack, loader

I am trying out webpack with react. I am trying to use babel-loader to transpile jsx files. I receive module not found error while using any webpack loaders/plugins. I have the required plugins installed in node_modules.

The issue seems to be with the path resolution. Somehow it prepends my current directory to the absolute path while resolving dependent plugins.

Here is my a snippet of my `webpack.config.js`

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
        query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
            plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
        }
    }]
}
```

It gives following error when I run `webpack` (globally as well as through npm)

```
ERROR in ../~/react/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropDevtool.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module '\\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js' in H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\react\lib
resolve module \\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js in H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\react\lib
  looking for modules in H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules
    resolve 'file' or 'directory' \users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js in H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules
      resolve file
        H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js doesn't exist
        H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js.webpack.js doesn't exist
        H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js.web.js doesn't exist
        H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js.js doesn't exist
        H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js.json doesn't exist
      resolve directory
        H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js\package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
        H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js doesn't exist (directory default file)
[H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js]
[H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js.webpack.js]
[H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js.web.js]
[H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js.js]
[H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js.json]
 @ ../~/react/lib/ReactDOMNullInputValuePropDevtool.js 1:0-102
```

Here `H:\codebase\react-demo\` is my project root directory. I.e `node_modules` resides in `H:\codebase\react-demo\`. It is trying to look up for dependency in `H:\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules`

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: In ReactDOMNullInputValuePropDevtool.js do you have `import '\\users\home\smeghani\private\codebase\react-demo\node_modules\process\browser.js'`?

Comment: No. ReactDOMNullInputValuePropDevtool.js is not my custom file. It is included as one of the node dependency (react-dom). So it does not have an import with hard coded path.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll delete my answer. I did look through the react code in github and apparently that file was just renamed to `ReactDOMNullInputValuePropHook.js`, and it doesn't seem to be importing process, so you could try an update.

Comment: Actually, this is just one example of error. I get the same error for any plugins I use. So it mostly seems, I am missing some configuration in webpack.config.js on how plugin dependencies should be resolved. I tried with resolve and resolveLoaders without any luck.

Comment: Can you post what your webpack config is regarding resolve and resolveLoaders is right now or were you setting those propertys when you got those errors?

Comment: Currently I have not set resolve or resolveLoaders. I have tried setting resolve and resolveLoaders as below 

var __dirname = path.resolve();

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname + "/app"),
    .
    module: {
        .
        },
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname);
    },
    resolveLoaders: {
        root: path.resolve(__dirname);
    }
};

I receive same errors with or without setting resolve/resolveLoaders.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120215/discussion-between-dogpawhat-and-sanket-meghani).

Answer (score 1):

I could work-around the issue. Initially, my project directories were on a mapped network drive. Moving the project directory to local drive (C:/) resolved the issue. Still not sure why it was causing the issue though.